# Rewriting .htaccess into apache config

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, apache, server

I have got myself a vserver.
I just thought off rewriting the context of the .htaccess (RewriteRules etc.) into
my /etc/apache2/sites-availabe/domain.conf .

Does this work?
Or does the .htaccess file have different functions that aren't
compatible with the apache config files?

Comment: Can you please explain in a little more detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited. Hope i got it better now^^

Answer (score 2):

The Joomla .htaccess includes many rules to rewrite your urls and secure your website. You *could* copy them to your vhost configuration, but, frankly, I would'nt recommend it: for starters, it seems like the kind of job giving you no benefit at all. Then some rules may change when you perform an update, and then you'll have to edit your vhost config again.